# Finding functions with $\phi (\lim_{p \to 0}||f||_p)=\int_{0}^1 (\phi \circ f)dm$

Tags: measure-theory

If $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ , for what functions $\phi$ on $[0,\infty)$ does the relation $$\phi (\lim_{p \to 0}||f||_p)=\int_{0}^1 (\phi \circ f)dm$$ hold for any bounded, measurable positive function $f$.

The given hint is to show $c\phi (x) +(1-c)\phi(1)=\phi(x^c)$ ($x>0$, $0 \le c \le 1$).

My attempt: By taking $f(t)= x \chi_{(0,c)}+\chi_{(c,0)}$ I got $c\phi (x) +(1-c)\phi(1)=\phi(x^c)$  this is because $\lim_{p\to 0}||f_p||=x^c$ , now what?

Also taking $f=x\chi_{(0,c)}$ gives $\phi(x)=\phi(0)$

Additional: According to user Mustafa Said the functions may be those which are concave and vanish at $0$.

Comment: Hint: Use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I get $\phi ( \int f) \le \phi (\lim_{p \to 0}||f||_p)$ , I don't see how that helps, this also imposes the requirement that $\phi$ be convex.

Comment: @MustafaSaid Where and how should I apply Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: After you have shown that such a function satisfies

$$c\phi(x) + (1-c)\phi(1) = \phi(x^c)\tag{1}$$

for $x > 0$ and $c\in [0,1]$, consider the function $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$\psi(t) = \phi(e^t).$$

What does $(1)$ translate to in terms of $\psi$?

Comment: I get $c\phi(x)+(1-c)\psi(0)=\phi(x^c)$, but I think that is not what you meant.

Comment: Indeed that is not what I meant. Only $\psi$ should appear, no more $\phi$.

Comment: so for $0 \le t \le 1$, we have $\psi(t)=t\psi(1)+(1-t)\psi(0)$, I'm not sure I can get anything if $t\ge 1$. So $\psi$ is a line in that interval.

Comment: You had no restriction that $x < e$ for $\phi$, or did you?

Comment: No, but I don't know what to do when $t\ge 1$ because I'm taking $c$ to be $t$

Comment: You shouldn't. Let $c$ be $c$, and just let $x = e^t$.

Comment: That was silly of me. (1) becomes $\psi(tc)-c\psi(t)=(1-c)\psi(0)$, so the difference depends on $c$ only, I can't seem to extract information from this.

Comment: I think it's better to keep things on the sides where they were for $\phi$, so $\psi(ct) = c\psi(t) + (1-c)\psi(0)$. Now, can you see which functions satisfy that relation?

Comment: This looks like equality in the inequality which defines convexity. So $\psi$ must be linear right?

Comment: Not "linear" in the "linear algebra" sense, since we need not have $\psi(0) = 0$. It's better to call such functions "affine" or "affine linear" to avoid ambiguity. But yes, $\psi$ must be affine. Therefore $\phi$ must be - what?

Comment: Then $\phi(t)=\phi(e^{\log(t)})=\psi(\log(t))=a\log(t)+b$. For some $a$ and $b$. I know $b=\psi(0)$ I can't figure out what $a$ is.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants that are in no way constrained by the identity $(1)$. Every choice of $(a,b)$ gives you a different $\phi$. Now, since it is clear that constants satisfy $\phi(\lim \lVert f\rVert_p) = \int (\phi\circ f)\,dm$, and that if $\phi_1,\phi_2$ have that property then $u\cdot\phi_1 + v\cdot \phi_2$ also has that property for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$, it only remains to check whether $\log$ has that property - then $a,b$ can be chosen arbitrarily - or not, and if not, then $a = 0$ is the only choice.

Comment: Well I've shown that $log(lim_{p\to 0}||f||_p)=\int_{0}^1 log|f|$ and since we are working with positive $f$ we can remove the absolute value. In which case (a,b) can be arbitrary, true?

Comment: Right. And so the functions with the desired property have been identified.

Answer (score 0):

I will outline the solution and tell you where to use Jensen's inequality and your job will be to fill in the details.

First, $m[0,1]=1$ and $f \in L^p[0,1]$ for some $p>0$ so $f \in L^q[0,1]$ for $0<q<p$.

Now show:

i) $\log||f||_q \geq \int \log |f|$ Here is where you use Jensen's inequality.

ii) $(\int |f|^q - 1)/q \geq \log ||f||_q$ and $(\int |f|^q - 1)/q \to \int \log |f|$ as $q \to 0$.

iii) $\lim_{q \to 0} ||f||_q = \exp(\int \log |f|)$

Comment: I've done this, ii) can be done using the dominated convergence theorem and iii) follows by i) ii) and the sandwich theorem. How does this help me in finding $\phi$? Must $\phi(f)=log|f|$?

Comment: I think that $\phi(x)$ must be a concave function that vanishes at $x=1$ but i'm not really sure.

Comment: The vanishing at $x=1$ seems to be true from the hint I proved, but I can't figure out the rest.

Comment: @user63697 how did you prove ii) ?  Didn't you use the inequality, $\log(x) \leq 1-x$?  Well this is true for any concave function that vanishes at 1.

Comment: To show $(\int |f|^q - 1)/q \geq \log ||f||_q$ I used the definition of $\log$ as a decreasing sequence , then I used dominated convergence with $|f|^r-1/r$

Comment: So if this inequality holds for all such functions, the proof should generalize right?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am guessing but I have to redo the problem to make sure.

Comment: Do you mean $\log(x) \le x-1$?

Comment: I've given up on the idea, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998065/a-property-of-concave-functions